# Build a normal distribution to approximate a discrete distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I have a discrete distribution of a sample of people by age:

```
age_bins <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80)

count <- c(250, 2300, 450, 140, 100, 70, 30)
```

so that the number of people in the age bin from 10 to 19 is 250, in the bin from 20 to 29 is 2300 etc. I'd like to build a normal distribution with approximately the same mean and shape. I know it is possible mathematically but struggle to do this in r. Could someone help please?

Comment: what do you mean by build a distribution?

Comment: age_bins and count lengths differ

Comment: Why are you not fitting a discreet distribution? I can think of no good reason why you would want to fit a normal distribution.

Comment: To start with the last, and very good, question. My objective is to measure a fit between two distributions, the theoretical one and the one generated by my model. Both are discrete, and my best idea was to approximate both by normal distributions and then produce a z-score. Should you have any better suggestions please let me know. Sorry for the age bins, they were meant as brackets so that the number of end points is the number of intervals plus one.

Comment: "My objective is to measure a fit between two distributions, the theoretical one and the one generated by my model." You should ask at stats.stackexchange.com for advice how to to that for discrete distributions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do this

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty not accurate but

```
approx_hist <- c(15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75)
g <- as.vector(rep(approx_hist, count))
hist(g, breaks = 7, prob = TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(g), sd = sd(g)), 
  col = "darkblue", lwd = 2, add= TRUE)
```

[image: norm?]

```
 dnorm(x, mean = mean(g), sd = sd(g))
```

might be normal distribution you want

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## Sample data

I disconsidered age_bin 80, since the length differed from count

```
age_bins <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70)
count <- c(250, 2300, 450, 140, 100, 70, 30)
```

## Creating data.frame with each observation

```
df <-
  tibble(
    age_bins = age_bins,
    count = count
  ) %>% 
  uncount(weights = count)
```

## Calculating mean and standard deviation

```
mu <- mean(df$age_bins)
sd <- sd(df$age_bins)
```

## ggplot2 histogram + normal distribution with calculated mean and sd above

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = age_bins)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..),
                 breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10), 
                 colour = "black", 
                 fill = "white") +
  stat_function(
    fun = dnorm,
    args = list(mean = mu, sd = sd))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ages are a) whole numbers and b) evenly distributed within the bins, this would work:

```
age_bins <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80)
count <- c(250, 2300, 450, 140, 100, 70, 30)
ages <- vector(mode="double")
for (i in seq_along(count)) {
  ages <- append(ages, round(runif(count[i], age_bins[i], age_bins[i+1]-1)))
}
hist(ages, breaks=7)
```

[image]